# Not getting any internet on my phone even though it says I'm connected to wifi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2, internet

My internet works fine on every other device in my house, and it connects correctly on my phone(Samsung galaxy S2), however when I try to load up any page on the browser, it says I'm not connected.

Can anyone suggest what may be the problem and what I can do to counter it.

Comment: Is it just the browser having that issue, or are other apps affected as well? Have you checked in *Settings › WiFi › More* what the status of the current WiFi AP is?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the network connection of your house's wifi not completely connected yet.

Do ensure that your phone display Connected to (name of your house's wifi) before you continue to surf the net.

Do take a look at the up and down arrow of the wifi connections that its moving as well. Else, try to on and off your wifi and try again till you are completely connected to your house wifi.

If not, you can try to on and off your modem of your house and try to on wifi on your device again.

Hope it helps!